# Why is my link not working in my react app?

Tags: reactjs

I've added links many times in React apps and have never run into this issue. The page displays the image, but the link isn't rendering. Is there something wrong with my syntax?
`<a href src="https://soundcloud.com/user-112780443/tracks" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img className="streamers__links-icons" src="./Images/Soundcloud_Icon.png" alt="Soundcloud" /></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the **URL** in the `href` attribute.

**change  :**

```
<a href src="https://soundcloud.com/user-112780443/tracks"...>
```

**to :**

```
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/user-112780443/tracks"....>
```

Comment: of course, thank you @monim clearly i've been staring at my screen too long.

Comment: Yeah ,It happens !